# What is the difference between angular2 and @angular/* npm packages

Tags: angular, npm

I just started learning Angular 2. While follow the official documents the dependence in `package.json`mention as `@angular/*` ex:@angular/common.
while checking the NPM site i found package named as [angular2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2).

- Which package i should install?
- What is the difference between this two packages?

Comment: Thanks Henka. so i should use @angular/* packages

Comment: At the time of writing, @angular is a lot more up-to-date.  They stopped updating "angular2" at beta17.  They're currently at RC4, and about to release rc5 (possibly next week).

Comment: i think they should mention this in "angular2" package page. At least it will reduce confusion.